# Remove a row from an Array of values by row index

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to remove rows from an array by row Index

I have

```
function test() {
arr1 = [[Id, From, To], [1.0, AA1, BB1], [2.0, AA2, BB2], [3.0, AA3, BB3], [4.0, AA4, BB4], [5.0, AA5, BB5], [6.0, AA6, BB6]]

arr1.splice(1,1);
return arr1
}
```

I get

```
[[Id, From, To], [2.0, AA2, BB2], [3.0, AA3, BB3], [4.0, AA4, BB4], [5.0, AA5, BB5], [6.0, AA6, BB6]]
```

Whitch is what I want

But If I have instead

```
function test() {
var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
arr1 = [[Id, From, To], [1.0, AA1, BB1], [2.0, AA2, BB2], [3.0, AA3, BB3], [4.0, AA4, BB4], [5.0, AA5, BB5], [6.0, AA6, BB6]]

var result = arr1.splice(1,1);

sht.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```

I get

```
result = [[1.0, AA1, BB1]]
```

I do not get what is going on, how do I get

```
result = [[Id, From, To], [2.0, AA2, BB2], [3.0, AA3, BB3], [4.0, AA4, BB4], [5.0, AA5, BB5], [6.0, AA6, BB6]]
```

Comment: why not simply use method [`deleteRow`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRow(Integer)) method ?

Comment: Return arr1 rather than the result array

Comment: @CodeManiac It'll be slow compared to whatever can be done inside js itself.

Comment: @op Quote your strings: `[["Id", "From","To"], [1.0,..` or provide number arrays. Your example isn't reproducible otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, carefully read the documentation on `splice()` method. When invoked on an `Array`, it takes three possible arguments:

1. `start` - index of `Array` element to start from;
2. `deleteCount` - number of elements to delete starting from `start`;
3. `item` - comma-separated list of values to replace deleted values by.

**Scenario 1**

As you invoke it with two arguments `splice(1,1)`, the method starts from index 1 (`[1.0, AA1, BB1]`), deletes only this element and replaces it with nothing, *mutating* the original `Array` as expected.

**Scenario 2**

The method also *returns* all elements you deleted as a separate `Array`, if you want to return the original `Array` (mutated by `splice()`), you will need to remove the `var result` and return the `arr1` directly.

**Useful links**

1. `splice()` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice);

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. I think I finally get the `mutating` of the original array thing, when that happens you do not assign to a variable. In VBA (which I am more familar with, there is no correspondence to that, that I am aware of

Comment: Glad I could help! 
Just keep in mind that Apps Script is based on JavaScript and thus adheres to rules that apply for JS (for the most part)